# Why do I see points on the line when doing a line plot in base R?

Tags: r, plot, sequence, line-plot

When I plot a sequence in a line plot in R using transparent color settings I keep getting these dots on the line. Do you have an idea why this is and how I could solve the problem?

```
s <-seq(1,100, by = 0.1)
plot(s, type="l",col=scales::alpha("black",0.3), lwd=3)
```

[image: Line plot in base R]

I tried using the lines function which resulted in the same problem.

Also, it is interesting to see how the the dots change with e.g. `s <-seq(1,100, by = 0.5)`

and disappear with `s <-seq(1,100, by = 1)`

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS 14.3.1
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I don't see this issue, I tried with `scales::alpha`. What packages are you using?

Comment: Using R or Rstudio, different operating systems, or different ways of saving the plot can all result in slightly different output plots, (particularly with regard to how they handle transparency) so if the answers below don't help it might be necessary to provide more information on your setup.

Comment: Yes, I am using the scales package. I specified the code.

And none of the proposed answers work in my case. It might indeed be an issue that I am using an older version of R (4.1.2 (2021-11-01)).

Comment: The bug is still there in 4.3.1; I don't have the very latest installed.

Comment: Please add output of `sessionInfo()` to your post, issue is likely due to OS.

Comment: I added the information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the line end style that is at play here.

The "line"-plot is drawn as a series of individual lines:

```
(0,0)    -> (1, 0.1)
(1, 0.1) -> (2, 0.2)
(2, 0.2) -> (3, 0.3)
...
```

At each end of the line, the default is to draw a "rounded line cap". You can see this at each extreme of the line. Two overlapping rounded caps, give the illusion of a small circle (or point).

These points are visible, because of your partial transparency.

A solution could be to try the two other options "butt" or "square":

```
plot(s, type="l",col=scales::alpha("black",0.3), lwd=3, lend=1)
plot(s, type="l",col=scales::alpha("black",0.3), lwd=3, lend=2)
```

See the `lend` parameter in `?par`.

Comment: Thank you, `lend=1` solved the problem for me!

Comment: Nice solution, but I think there's more going on.  The original code had 1000 segments, but only 9 blobs.  I saw similar results on some graphics devices.  I'd guess there's some rounding error happening so the joints aren't seen as joints some of the time.

Comment: I agree, there is something else going on, but it is difficult to reproduce.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug in some graphics drivers, but not others.  In MacOS I see it if I use `quartz()`, `pdf()`, `png()` or `jpeg()` devices.  I don't see it in `X11()`, the default device in RStudio, or the devices in the `ragg` package.

So the solution is to use a device that doesn't have the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can set value `v=0` in `rainbow`. No need for `scales::alpha` package or customizing a function (if it's just black).

```
> plot(s, type="l", col=rainbow(n=1, v=0, alpha=.3), lwd=3)
```

[image]

*Note:* I am on Linux.

---

*Data:*

```
s <- seq(1, 100, by=0.1)
```

Comment: That gives the same results as the original code.  It all depends on which graphics device you use.

Comment: @user2554330 I see, so it's a MacOS bug. You could file it at R-bugs.

Comment: So, same question, if you couldn't reproduce the issue, why answer

Comment: I am using MacOS so it really might be a bug.

Comment: @zx8754 there are lots of questions here that get answered without fully reproducible code, unambiguous expected output and session info. To me it seems standard (and reasonable) that people try to help with the information that's available, based on what they think the question means. Also SO encourages this with the reputation system. I agree that it would be better if it didn't in some cases - it seems perverse to me that answering an obvious duplicate tends to get rep but closing it doesn't. This is all off-topic for this question though. Perhaps you should raise the issue on meta?

Comment: @SamR this isn't one of those posts where you can guess the answer based on limited info. The code in this post is so simple and it has to work just by looking at the code without testing, yet it doesn't. In this case, we have to first understand the issue properly to suggest an answer that actually works.

Comment: @zx8754 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  based on the now-accepted answer, I'm not convinced